# JavaFX - What do I need to pass in the forTableColumn() for a CheckBoxTableCell

Tags: java, javafx

So in my code I have a table that has multiple editable columns.

Some are text , some have a drop-down menu and others are choice boxes (true/false)

This is how to columns are setup:

```java
usernameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
usernameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User,String>("username"));
permissionLevelCol.setCellFactory(ChoiceBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(/* this is a String[]*/usersManager.getPermissionNamesList()));
permissionLevelCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User,String>("permissionLevel"));
giveRefundsCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn());
giveRefundsCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PermissionLevel, CheckBoxTableCell>("giveRefunds"));
```

This works for the `TextFieldTableCell` and the `ChoiceBoxTableCell` but I don't know what to put for the `ChoiceBoxTableCell` - it wants a parameter in the `CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn()`

Error message:

> Error:(56, 56) java: no suitable method found for forTableColumn(no
>   arguments)
>       method javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(javafx.scene.control.TableColumn) is not applicable
>         (cannot infer type-variable(s) S
>           (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
>       method javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(javafx.util.Callback>)
>   is not applicable
>         (cannot infer type-variable(s) S,T
>           (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
>       method javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(javafx.util.Callback>,boolean)
>   is not applicable
>         (cannot infer type-variable(s) S,T
>           (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
>       method javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(javafx.util.Callback>,javafx.util.StringConverter)
>   is not applicable
>         (cannot infer type-variable(s) S,T
>           (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))

ps:Line 56 from the error message is the line `giveRefundsCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn());`

Comment: and please read the api doc ... which boils down to require a boolean column

Comment: @kleopatra stop copy pasting the same reply to everything. If it's not **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example** enough for you just go to another question

Comment: @kleopatra I read that but what boolean column shall I pass? The usernameCol and permissionLevelCol didn't need to pass a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just pass the column itself.

```
giveRefundsCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(giveRefundsCol));
```

Fun story it isn't used in the Oracle source code, you could just pass null It would work the same

```
public static <S> Callback<TableColumn<S,Boolean>, TableCell<S,Boolean>> forTableColumn(
        final TableColumn<S, Boolean> column) {
    return forTableColumn(null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this after the Line 56 code displaying error.
' giveRefundsCol.setSelected(true) '

It should be able to capture the data made for the checkbox and set it to checked.

Comment: TableColumn doesn't hava a method for setSelected(true)

error message

Error:(57, 23) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setSelected(boolean)
  location: variable giveRefundsCol of type javafx.scene.control.TableColumn